# Transform curl PUT Command into Python request.put

Tags: python, curl

I would like to turn this curl command:

```
curl -v -k -X PUT -u user:passwd --data-binary @somefile -H 'Content-Type:text/plain' https://192.168.0.22/dir/subdir
```

into a python request.put command.

I have seen quite a few examples of POST transformations on this forum, yet the '--data-binary @somefile' type of parameter does not appear to have a translation.

I have tried at least the two following arrangements:

```
auth = ('user', passwd)
headers = {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'}
data = '-v -k -X --data-binary @somefile'
requests.put(uri, auth=auth, headers=headers, data=data, verify=False)


auth = ('user', passwd)
headers = {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'}
somefile=open('somefile','rb')
requests.put(uri, auth=auth, headers=headers, data={'somefile': somefile}, verify=False)
```

The given curl command works from a command prompt, but I can't seem to get the correct syntax into python.

Can anyone shed some light on a what I might try next?

thanks,

q-bit

Comment: Have you tried the second command except with `data=somefile.read()`? You can't exactly send a file pointer in a HTTP request, you want to read the file first. And no need to put it inside a dictionary, just read the contents and send them.

Comment: thanks @GreenCloakGuy, I am at least getting a response from the server: '403 Client Error: Forbidden for url: https://192...'  But still no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Send the file handler as data, not keeping it inside a dict

```
auth = ('user', passwd)
headers = {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'}
somefile=open('somefile','r')
requests.put(uri, auth=auth, headers=headers, data=somefile, verify=False)
```

Or

```
file = {'file': ('somefile', open('somefile','r'), 'text/plain' )}
requests.put(url, auth=auth, headers=headers, files=file, verify=False)
```

And you don't need to read the file content, `requests` already does that for streamable `data` & `files` parameters.

Comment: thanks @Tushar,

the first method provides a 403 response.  however, when I 

    `print(somefile.read())`

there are '\r\n\r\' control characters added within the file.  How can I NOT do this?

the second method provides a 403 response as well.  and 

    `print(license_file['license_file'][1].read())`

gives the same control character additions.

Comment: I just said you don't need to. But even passing it with `.read()` should work. The file is a text file? If not, did you try changing `text/plain` to other options? I have seen curl being more forgiving in terms of content-type.

Comment: I understand, the only reason I utilized the read() method was to get a look at what the file looked like after Python picked it up.

However, it was your suggestion regarding changing to 'other options'.  I ended up opening the file as 'r' and not 'rb'.  that seemed to keep the control chars at bay.

Comment: Ohhh... my bad. I had done it for binary files. So posted that. Edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This was the code that enabled the script to load the file:

```
somefile = open('somefile','r')
response = requests.put(uri, auth=auth, headers=headers, files={'--data-binary':somefile}, verify=False)
```

I appreciate the help.

thanks,

q-bit